# How do check if a PHP session is empty?

Tags: php, session

Is this bad practice?

```
if ($_SESSION['something'] == '')
{
    echo 'the session is empty';
}
```

Is there a way to check if its empty or it is not set? I'm actualy doing this:

```
if (($_SESSION['something'] == '') || (!isset($_SESSION['something'])) {
    echo 'the session is either empty or doesn\'t exist';
}
```

Does `!isset` just checks if a `$_SESSION['']` exist and doesn't check if, is there are values in the array or not

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I would use [`isset`](http://www.php.net/isset) and [`empty`](http://www.php.net/empty):

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['blah']) && !empty($_SESSION['blah'])) {
   echo 'Set and not empty, and no undefined index error!';
}
```

[`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists) is a nice alternative to using `isset` to check for keys:

```
session_start();
if(array_key_exists('blah',$_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION['blah'])) {
    echo 'Set and not empty, and no undefined index error!';
}
```

Make sure you're calling `session_start` before reading from or writing to the session array.

Comment: no need to use isset if you are already using empty. empty will also check if the variable exists, i.e. is not null/undefined

Comment: No need to use isset AND empty.

Comment: @knittl It's good practice to actually make sure you have the variable before testing to see if it's empty.

Comment: @knittl - but then we don't know if it's been set or not, whether it's not set *or* empty true will be returned. I tend to use the above, but it might not always be needed.

Comment: Empty return false when not exist or null or "" or empty array. Why would you need to check if isset too? Read the help file : http://ca.php.net/empty

Comment: @Daok Variables can both exist and be blank. Checking to see if it exists AND is empty is a good idea.

Comment: usually you either want to check if the variable exists (`isset`) or if it contains any value evaluating to false (0, "0", null, false, …) (`empty`). `empty` will also return true on unset variables, so you don’t need `isset` first

Comment: @random it is __not__ good practice! Its just redundant. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty

Comment: The issue I have is when I do form submission it shows the session isn't empty but doesn't pull value for the session for some reason. Any idea why that may happen.

Comment: So I have to use `isset` or checking `empty` is sufficient enough?

Comment: oh wow, on my logout page, I forgot to call the session_start(); at the top of the page, otherwise it would run without any errors, and without actually unsetting the session variables.

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins If you do not check empty it will try to do some strange things like: Array to string conversion in It tries to take your empty session log and convert to an array.....

Answer (score 12):

Use `isset`, `empty` or `array_key_exists` (especially for array keys) before accessing a variable whose existence you are not sure of. So change the order in your second example:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['something']) || $_SESSION['something'] == '')
```

Answer (score 6):

you are looking for PHP’s [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) function

Comment: empty is dangerous because it also reports false, 0 and "0" as empty.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the count() function to see how many entries there are in the $_SESSION array. This is not good practice. You should instead set the id of the user (or something similar) to check wheter the session was initialised or not.

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['uid']) )
    die( "Login required." );
```

(Assuming you want to check if someone is logged in)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check whether sessions are available, you probably want to use the [`session_id()`](http://php.net/session_id) function:

> session_id() returns the session id for the current session or the empty string ("") if there is no current session (no current session id exists).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION))
{}
else
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I ran into an issue where I was running a function after checking if there was a session.  It would throw an error everytime I tried loading the page after logging out, still worked just logged an error page.  Make sure you use exit(); if you are running into the same problem.

```
     function sessionexists(){
        if(!empty($_SESSION)){
     return true;
         }else{
     return false;
         }
      }


        if (!sessionexists()){
           redirect("https://www.yoursite.com/");
           exit();
           }else{call_user_func('check_the_page');
         }
```