# PHP Sessions - Login Form - Unable to login

Tags: php, mysql, session, login-script

I have a simple script where a user logs in. I am trying to use sessions, so that a user remains logged in on whatever page he browses through the website.

I have these scripts:

- index.php - http://pastebin.com/yqLtqPRC
- login.php - http://pastebin.com/KcQWjfw1
- dbConfig.php -    http://pastebin.com/GKyfaJJV
- upload.php -    http://pastebin.com/iMrz3WB8
- functions.php -    http://pastebin.com/x44KrmxK

If the user logs in or is logged in, 'You are now logged in, $user' is supposed to be shown, but the default 'You are not logged in.' displays throughout the pages.

No error messages are shown whenever I change page or try to log in.

**Latest version of the code can be found here:** http://www.mediafire.com/?7n6qo3p4gpkaao4

Can anyone help please?

thanks.

Comment: Are you using multiple servers with a load balancer? When I was first developing a web application with login, I ran into a problem where the login took place on one server, but later page loads went to a different server without the session data. We configured client persistence in the load balancer to address this.

Answer (score 5):

Put the `session_start()` on the top of the page in each file where you need sessions just after`<?php` and you should be fine.  You need to call this function before any actual html is echo'd on the page.

Read the php session documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Further looking into your code, if you want to limit the user to see other pages only if he's logged in then make a new file called `logincheck.php` with contents below and include it on the top of each file by `require_once("logincheck.php");`.  In this case don't put the `session_start()` code again as mentioned above.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    $welcomeMsg = "<p align='right'>Welcome, </p>" .$_SESSION["username"];
}else{
    if(basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])=="index.php")
        $welcomeMsg = "You are not logged in";
    else
        header("Location:index.php");//will redirect the user to index page if he has not logged in
}
?>
```

Now u can use `$welcomeMsg` and echo it anywhere on page where u want to display the error msg.

Hope that helps answer your query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did as you said, tried with index.php and files.php. Whenever I try to login it redirects to a blank page (login.php) and nothing happens. Could something be wwrong with this line `<?php if(isset($_GET['op'])){ require_once("login.php"); } ?>`

Comment: I tried fiddling a bit with the code.. which can be found here: http://pastebin.com/DTzw16XP . I get an error message: 
`Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2PHP\final\logincheck.php on line 2`

Comment: @Brian that's what i wrote in my answer if you include the logincheck.php file then don't write session_start() at the top of the page.  Instead include the logincheck.php on the top of the page which would manage to check if the user has logged in.  Take a look here. http://pastebin.com/ND6jZVpR

Comment: @Brian also your code has many glitches which would deem it not optimal but for the sake of the question at the moment I would not go there as that's an entirely a different topic.  But if you need help i'd be glad to help.  The above patch should get you started on the right track though.

Comment: yes, but the user still doesn't log in. "You are not logged in" is still shown. Is this line correct? `<form action="?op" method="POST">`

Comment: @Brian He is logging in I think but I'd look into it.  Can u send me the final copy of the whole thing you did till now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21528/discussion-between-lonewolfs-and-brian)

Answer (score 2):

form action="?op=login" method="POST" action="login.php"

why are using action twice in form?

action="login.php" is only required.

Comment: and i totally agree with what Theolodis said

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see exactly where your problem was, too much code to read, but by looking through 2 files (the first 2) I noticed some stuff that could become a problem:
A Session_id is supposed to identify a user. if you simply put in a boolean (true) I could easily break in your user reserved part of the site by just modifying my HTTP header.
second thing is that you put a redirect on the login.php before you echo something.... guess you wont see anything.... the redirect happens before the echo.
The third thing is that you should definetly hash the passwords you get and store. It is so sad when people get access to databases and have without any work all passwords of all people.

And a last advice: try to put the Session_Start as the first statement in every file... could be that.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped at this point:

```
redirect('../TASK2PHP/upload.php');
```

what's that function and what does it do?

Maybe you meant to use [http_redirect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php) or [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) or [HttpResponse::redirect](http://php.net/manual/en/httpresponse.redirect.php) ...

Comment: It's defined in functions.php

Comment: oh ok. I'd have to look deeper into the sources before having another go.

Comment: All it does is `header('Location: '.$page);`, pretty much as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. There were a ton of errors.

http://www.2shared.com/file/A2V_Ztw8/login.html

That should at least get you started. It is also commented along the way. I did not use the functions.php file there was nothing important in there. Also when you use this change your dbConfig file accordingly.

Comment: That gives me an error `Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2PHP\final\login.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2PHP\final\login.php on line 37` on login

Comment: yeah you haven't created a user in the database yet. Create a user with the username 'abc' and password '123'. Make sure the attributes (columns) in the database table are 'username' and 'password'. Those are the indexes it's referring to.

Comment: You can create some sort of check to see if the results returned from the query are actually there and put the foreach loop inside of it. Something like if (mysql_num_rows($result)> 0) { foreach loop stuff }. That way session variables will only be created if the query returns results. I failed to put that part.

Comment: Better yet change line 33 to if($results > 0){ that will do the same thing as the comment above.

Comment: I get the same error, even if I tried multiple users. The columns are called Username and Password

Comment: Did some more research. A notice error is not fatal, it's just saying "hey, these two variables have not been set yet." The notice is referring to the Session variables. To fix it you put it in isset brackets. So use this login.php http://pastebin.com/JnR1kC7g

Comment: Is your version working? I tried it and it doesn't login, no error messages, and even if I try to login with wrong credentials no error messages are shown

Answer (score 0):

I have edited index.php, login.php and setup working flow of sessions. Follow the code structure for setting up sessions in others file accordingly.
Download following login-form rar file;
https://www.box.com/s/1ie9ilp9jgluvokf6say

Comment: I have tried the files, and made alterations for the sessions, however when I login the page is 'refreshed' and 'You are not logged in' still appears.

Comment: Can you please tell me that which file you have run?

Answer (score 0):

you code structure of login methods seems confusing and its always a good idea to echo everything before you redirect otherwise httpresponse complains about it. Moreover my advise is you first turn on error reporting its always a good idea to do development with error reporting enabled. You can do this inside your login.php just place at the beginning of the file.
**error_reporting(E_ALL); or set E_ALL to 1
ini_set('display_errors','On');**

Answer (score 0):

TL,DR.  But here is an article that teaches the general design pattern for this sort of thing.  All web sites that use PHP client authentication follow this design.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/A_2391-PHP-login-logout-and-easy-access-control.html

You can copy and paste the code snippets from the article.  If you have any questions about what the code is doing, please post a comment here and I'll try to help explain. ~Ray

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help :
you can debug if session is empty or not.

`session_id()` returns the string identifying the current session. If a session hasn't been initialized, it will return an empty string.

```
 if(session_id() == '')
 {
      // session has NOT been started
      session_start();
 }
 else
 {
      // session has been started
 }
```

**and**

[check session in php if empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519818/how-do-check-if-a-php-session-is-empty)

Answer (score 0):

Make it on index.php file and include your pages if user logged in. and check inside each and every page you including. if user not set then redirect to login page.

example :

## index.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION['UserId'])){ 
      //make simple function to get the username from user ID
        $dUserName = getUserName($_SESSION['UserId']);
        echo "wellcome".$dUserName;
        echo "<href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
else{
      echo "<href='login.php'>Logout</a>";
}
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
   $includePage = "includes/".$_GET['page'].".php";
}
else{
     $includePage = "includes/login.php";
}
if(isset($includePage)){
  include($includePage);
}
```

sample page loading from index

## sample.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != ''){
       //show your page
}
else{
      //redirect to login page
      echo '<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">window.location="index.php?page=login";</SCRIPT>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed the files...

The main problem is in `login.php` in the `loginUser` function.

Change this line:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '$username' AND Password = '$password'";
```

To this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'";
```

The problem with the first line is that it is looking for the text '$username' (and '$password' and not the variable `$username` and `$password`

As you can see the solution is to close the string before and after the variables reference'

P.S. You would gain tremendously from using a framework such as CodeIgniter to build your site, besides for saving you a lot of time fixing errors like this, it is also much more secure.

Let me know if you need me to upload the fixed files.

Comment: PHP interpolates variables in double-quoted strings.

Comment: maybe true, but it fixed the problem with loading the username

Comment: additionally i think you are overlooking the fact that the variable was also enclosed in single quotes

Comment: Single quotes inside double quotes have no special meaning, they don't prevent interpolation.

Comment: Best, of course, would be for him to convert to mysqli or PDO and use prepared statements.

Comment: I'll have to diff my files with his to see what other change i made that fixed it