# How would you properly write this statement?

Tags: php, html, web, syntax

New PHP programmer here. Need some syntax help.

Like I know what im trying to do, here, check if that session variable is set and if its a certain string value, but the "(" you need for isset is messing the syntax up. I can't find the help im looking for via google for what is really a very simple syntax question, so I had to come here.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['IsValid'] AND $_SESSION['IsValid']=="Yes")) {


}else{


}
```

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['IsValid']) && ($_SESSION['IsValid']=="Yes"))` --- `&&` has precedence over `AND` ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do check if a PHP session is empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519818/how-do-check-if-a-php-session-is-empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typos:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['IsValid']) AND $_SESSION['IsValid']=="Yes") {
                              ^---missing                      ^---only one ) here
```

isset() is a function and checks a SINGLE variable if it "exists". You're trying to isset() the result of your `AND` operation, which is illegal syntax.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( isset($_SESSION['IsValid']) && $_SESSION['IsValid'] == "Yes" ) {
```